# Deployment failure: Failed opening required '/var/app/ondeck/vendor/autoload.php'

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've come across a problem that I really don't understand. I've developed a local composer package for my Laravel app (based on an existing one that didn't do exactly what I needed it to), and now I can no longer successfully deploy my app to my AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance.

I believe my new local composer package was created correctly: I took the original composer package, moved it to a new folder called "packages" in my Laravel app root. I added a `repositories` entry to my `composer.json` that pointed to it:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "packages/konsulting/justgiving-api-sdk"
    }
]
```

I then ran `composer require konsulting/justgiving-api-sdk @dev` and the local package was installed successfully. It works locally with no issues.

But now deploy to EB, I get the following error:

> Activity execution failed, because: PHP Warning: 
>   require(/var/app/ondeck/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in /var/app/ondeck/artisan on line 18   PHP
>   Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/app/ondeck/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear7:/usr/share/php') in
>   /var/app/ondeck/artisan on line 18
>   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)

What could be causing this issue? Literally nothing but this composer package (which works locally) is different.

I've tried `composer dumpautoload` and `composer update`.

Comment: How did you deploy your application?

Comment: Did you check if `/var/app/ondeck/vendor/autoload.php` exist on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simple, but confusing. I just needed to disable symlinking in `repositories {}`.

```
"options": {
    "symlink": false
}
```

Works fine now!